# How to split a column in R?

Tags: r, split

Anyone know how can I split a column to multiple ones?
For example: I want to split column "score" and "class", then make the values of column "grade" as column name. In my data, I have **50 different values** in column "grade" instead of only two in the example below.
In the data frame 2, the row names are the values of column "class" in data frame 1.

data frame 1

```
class   grade   score
A          a    12
B          a    45
C          a    75
D          a    18
E          a    6
A          b    45
B          b    92
C          b    78
D          b    36
E          b    39
```

data frame 2

```
    a   b
A   12  45
B   45  92
C   75  78
D   18  36
E   6   39
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R's `unstack` does this out of the box:

```
unstack(df, score ~ grade)
#   a  b
#1 12 45
#2 45 92
#3 75 78
#4 18 36
#5  6 39
```

As does `xtabs`:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(score ~ class + grade, data=df))

#   a  b
#A 12 45
#B 45 92
#C 75 78
#D 18 36
#E  6 39
```

Comment: Well sure, if you're into terribly simple and straightforward answers.

Comment: @RichardScriven - your `reshape` answer is good though, as it doesn't rely on any sorting or data order.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(df, class ~ grade, value.var = "score")
  class  a  b
1     1 12 45
2     2 45 92
3     3 75 78
4     4 18 36
5     5  6 39

df <- structure(list(class = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L), grade = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), score = c(12L, 
45L, 75L, 18L, 6L, 45L, 92L, 78L, 36L, 39L)), .Names = c("class", 
"grade", "score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `spread` from `library(tidyr)`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, grade, score)
```