# Reshape data frame where column names are a single variable in initial data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Any ideas on how I should transpose or reshape my data frame from this:

```
    value               L2
1   2008-09-01T07:00:00 timestamp
2   621.31              ht
3   0                   X3
4   2008-09-02T07:00:00 timestamp
5   621.24              ht
6   0                   X3
7   2008-09-03T07:00:00 timestamp
8   621.25  ht
9   0                   X3
```

To this:

```
    timestamp           ht      X3
1   2008-09-01T07:00:00 621.31  0
2   2008-09-02T07:00:00 621.24  0
3   2008-09-03T07:00:00 621.25  0
```

I'm trying to change the 2nd column into column names and keeping the `timestamp` and `ht` records paired.

*The title needs some work, if someone has a better idea I'd be happy to try and change it.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006760/how-to-split-a-column-in-r/33006862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `unstack` in base R will do the trick:

```
unstack(df)

      ht           timestamp X3
1 621.31 2008-09-01T07:00:00  0
2 621.24 2008-09-02T07:00:00  0
3 621.25 2008-09-03T07:00:00  0
```

This function is great to turn a two column data.frame where one column is values and the other names the variables into a wide data.frame of the appropriate shape.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="    value               L2
1   2008-09-01T07:00:00 timestamp
2   621.31              ht
3   0                   X3
4   2008-09-02T07:00:00 timestamp
5   621.24              ht
6   0                   X3
7   2008-09-03T07:00:00 timestamp
8   621.25  ht
9   0                   X3")
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a simple answer. +1 for a base R solution. Cheers!